# U1 music mp3 files not put into albums

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, id3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mp3s synced on Ubuntu One not showing up under artist or album](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130128/mp3s-synced-on-ubuntu-one-not-showing-up-under-artist-or-album)

Via the web page I can see that my files sync to U1 cloud servers. For the mp3 files, there seems to be a problem that several questions have already addressed but there does not seem to be a clear answer. If I use EasyTAG 2.1.6, I can see the ID3 tags on the local files and they seem to correctly define the artist, album title and track name. I expect it is not relevant, but I am using 10.04 with several different clients to rip the CDs.

However, some mp3 files do not appear in the cloud at all and some others get assigned to Various Artist or Unknown artist. Does the music streaming (e.g. via Ipad) use the tags or the directory/file structure to assign the artist or album, and how quickly should it be expected to work? :-)

Which version of ID3 tags does U1 music streaming work best with or prefer?

thanks for any help

David

Answer (score 0):

The process of metadata (read: id3 tags) extraction from the music files could take a while. As such, you might not see the music files sorted correctly immediately. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130128) is relevant.