# Mp3s synced on Ubuntu One not showing up under artist or album

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, music, indexing

I have synced approximately 10GB of music with U1 over the last 48 hours. Nearly everything appears OK: the songs are tagged correctly, I can queue and play them. However, with the exception of a few that I uploaded first, all of them don't appear under Artist or Album and I can't use the search to find them. I can only find them under Song.

Am I just being impatient and U1 just needs time to index these mp3s, or is something wrong?

Comment: The music metadata scanning is handled asynchronously on our end, so it is possible that some files didn't show up immediately.  Has the situation improved since you asked this question?

Answer (score 2):

I was describing a similar situation here, but while I was writing, all uploaded music of mine got categorized, so I assume the whole process can take good 24 hours from the moment one have uploaded music to the cloud =). Hope this information will be helpful.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114226/) is also relevant.